# lateinit property apiComponent has not been initialized in Dagger 2

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, retrofit2, dagger-2

I'm trying to implement Dragger 2 in recyclerview but I'm getting following error when running the app:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property apiComponent has not been initialized
        at com.kabelash.squarerepos.MyRetroApplication$Companion.getApiComponent(MyRetroApplication.kt:18)
        at com.kabelash.squarerepos.network.viewmodel.RetroViewModelFactory.create(RetroViewModelFactory.kt:21)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:164)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:130)
        at com.kabelash.squarerepos.network.view.RetroFragment.initViewModel(RetroFragment.kt:43)
        at com.kabelash.squarerepos.network.view.RetroFragment.onCreate(RetroFragment.kt:29)
```

APIComponent.kt

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class, APIModule::class])
interface APIComponent {
    fun inject(retrofitRepository: RetrofitRepository)
    fun inject(retroViewModel: RetroViewModel)
    fun inject(retroFragment: RetroFragment)
    fun inject(retroViewModelFactory: RetroViewModelFactory)
}
```

NetworkActivity.kt
class NetworkActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.network_layout)
    replaceFragment()
}


fun replaceFragment(){
   supportFragmentManager
       .beginTransaction()
       .replace(R.id.container_retro_room, RetroFragment())
       .commit()
}
```

}

RetroFragment.kt

```
class RetroFragment: Fragment() {

    lateinit var retroViewModel: RetroViewModel
    var fragmentView:View?=null
    private  var listAdapter: PostListAdapter?=null
    private var  postListLayoutBinding:PostListLayoutBinding?=null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        initViewModel()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        postListLayoutBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.post_list_layout,container,false)
        fragmentView = postListLayoutBinding?.root
        initAdapter()
        setAdapter()
        fetchRetroInfo()
        return  fragmentView
    }

    fun  initViewModel(){
        var retroViewModelFactory = RetroViewModelFactory()
        retroViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,retroViewModelFactory).get(RetroViewModel::class.java)
    }

    fun fetchRetroInfo(){
        retroViewModel.postInfoLiveData?.observe(this,object:Observer<List<PostInfo>>{
            override fun onChanged(t: List<PostInfo>?) {
                t?.apply {
                    listAdapter?.setAdapterList(t)
                }


            }
        })
    }

    private fun setAdapter(){
        fragmentView?.post_list?.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(activity, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
            adapter = listAdapter
        }

    }

   private fun initAdapter(){
       listAdapter = PostListAdapter(this@RetroFragment.requireActivity())
   }

}
```

RetroViewModelFactory.kt
class RetroViewModelFactory : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    lateinit var apiComponent: APIComponent
    @Inject
    lateinit var retrofitRepository: RetrofitRepository

```
override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
 //   initDaggerComponent()
   var apiComponent : APIComponent =  MyRetroApplication.apiComponent
    apiComponent.inject(this)
    if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(RetroViewModel::class.java)) {
        return RetroViewModel(retrofitRepository) as T
    }
    throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
}

fun initDaggerComponent(){
    apiComponent =   DaggerAPIComponent
        .builder()
        .aPIModule(APIModule(APIURL.BASE_URL))
        .build()
    apiComponent.inject(this)
}
```

}

Can someone help to fix this issue? I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the exception message says, you have a property called `apiComponent` marked with `lateinit` in your `MyRetroApplication` class, which has not been initialized. A `lateinit` property causes this exception if you attempt to read its value (such as here, within the factory) before setting it. You should create an instance of `APIComponent` in the `MyRetroApplication` class when your application starts, and assign it to that property.

Comment: Please see the edit section above for my MyRetroApplication class. I think that I created it properly. What am I missing there?

Comment: It's a bit redundant, for example, `initDaggerComponent` both sets the value of `apiComponent` and then returns it and sets it again, but that should still be fine. Do you have `MyRetroApplication` set as the application class to use in your Manifest file? My suspicion would be that that's missing, which would cause none of the code within this class to be ever executed.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You are a life saver. I missed to declare application class in the manifest.